# Visual Studio Code: How to debug javascript code inside a Spring Boot application?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am developing a Spring Boot application using Java 12 and Maven.
I can debug the Java code without any problems.
However, I was not able to configure the debugger to also be able to debug the javascript code in the front-end side of the application.
How can I do it?

This is my launch.json file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8888",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main/java/resources/static"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - WexManagerApplication",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "wexmanager/br.com.aquario.wexmanager.WexManagerApplication",
            "projectName": "wexmanager"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to run two debuggers at the same time: One for the back-end and one for the front-end, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You should be able to use Developer Tools on your browser to debug javascript.

Comment: Sure. But I want to use vscode ;)

Comment: have you try to change the  "type" value to "node" ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT no. I'm using java, not nodejs

Comment: I had the same problem.  The only way I've been able to do it is to run VSC/Node on the front and Eclipse/Spring Boot on the back.  Seems like a hack so please report if you found a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `serverReadyAction` under your Java launch configuration.

```
{
    "type": "java",
    "name": "Launch Dev AppServer",
    "request": "launch",
    "mainClass": "AppServer",
    "projectName": "App",
    "serverReadyAction": {
        "action": "debugWithChrome",
        "pattern": "Started SelectChannelConnector@[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+:([0-9]+)",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main/resources"
    }
}
```

`action` specifies the debug environment to use, `pattern` is a regular expression that will match the console output when the server is ready to accept connections (the port number that the server is listening on should be captured), and `webRoot` needs to point to the root JavaScript source file location.

This configuration is sufficient if you deploy unprocessed JavaScript but if you use a bundler like webpack you'll also need to create source maps and set the `outFiles` property appropriately.

Full documentation on configuring the ServerReadyAction JavaScript debug environment here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/blob/main/OPTIONS.md